# Elastic Search index search method issue

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-api-gateway

I have created an index on my ES domain with method PUT using postman. Now when I do `/_search` on my index I see the issue of parsing exception. I am not sure what is action in the error response

Issue :
Below I have added my index settings and mapping for my ES domain and all the S3 document are available on the index because using AWS API gateway post-call I can see the data but the search is not working when I send from my website 
`Get` mydomainName/{index}/_search

```
 [{
        "error": {
            "root_cause": \[
                {
                    "type": "parsing_exception",
                    "reason": "Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in \[actions\].",
                    "line": 2,
                    "col": 5
                }
            \],
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in \[actions\].",
            "line": 2,
            "col": 5
        },
        "status": 400
    }][1]
```

`PUT` mydomainName/{index}

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "section": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "boost": 10
        },
        "url": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: What's your query then?

Comment: can you provide your search query?